# Trying to get reddit's api to works in node JS, return error 403. where am i wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, reddit

I'm working on a node project that requires to use the reddit API.

My probleme here is that when i try to do a api call, it return 403.

The thing is that for some api routes, it works fine but not for thoses i want to use.

Here's my code :

```html
const axios = require('axios');

const redditClientID = 'the id'
const redditClientSecret = 'the secret'

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/reddit', function(req, res) {
        res.redirect(`https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=${redditClientID}&response_type=code&state=RJIV5oTRU27BBNaPpqkU&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/reddit/callback&duration=temporary&scope=identity,submit,save,privatemessages,vote`)
    });

    app.get('/reddit/callback', (req, res) => {
        const code = req.query.code
        const encodedHeader = Buffer.from(`${redditClientID}:${redditClientSecret}`).toString("base64")
        axios ({
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token`,
            data: `grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/reddit/callback`,
            headers: {
                authorization: `Basic ${encodedHeader}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'User-Agent': 'web:PocArea:V0.1 by Me'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            access_token = response.data.access_token
            console.log(access_token);
            getPostScore(access_token, "wxoezm")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err });
        });
    })

    function getPostScore(redditKey, postId) {
        return axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `https://oauth.reddit.com/api/info?id=${postId}`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${redditKey}`,
                'User-Agent': 'myBot/0.0.1'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            var resp = response.data;
            console.log(resp);
            return;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(`Error retrieving post ${postId} score: `, error);
        });
    }

    function sendPrivateMessage(redditKey) {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://oauth.reddit.com/api/compose`,
            data: {
                api_type: 'json',
                subject: 'objet du message privé',
                text: 'salut, voici un mp de la part de larea',
                to: 'KumaYes',
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${redditKey}`,
                'User-Agent': 'myBot/0.0.1'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            var resp = response.data;
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(`Erreur lors de la récupération des issues du dépôt alaborde29/GithubAREA: `, error);
        });
    }
}
```

It works for routes like "api/v1/me" but for other routes i'm kinda lost.

I'll use the two function at the bottom (sendMessage and getPostScore)

Am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that you have properly authenticated your app with Reddit API by obtaining an access token. However, you are making a GET request to the api/info endpoint with a id parameter, which is returning a 403 error. This could be because you do not have sufficient permissions to access this endpoint with the scopes you have requested.